# Unknown command error in Jenkins when running Cake script using Powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Our Jenkins server has been successfully building projects for years using Powershell to run a cake script. Out of the blue today, we started getting the following error on multiple projects:

```
12:10:46 Running build script...
12:10:46 
12:10:46 Error: Unknown command 'Default'.
12:10:46 
12:10:46        .\scripts\build.cake -target=Default -configuration=Release 
12:10:46 -verbosity=Verbose -environment=dev -certificatePath=C:/Program Files 
12:10:46 (x86)/xxxxx/Verisign Certificate -certificateName=xxxxxxxx_cert.pfx 
12:10:46 -certificatePassword=xxxxxxxxxxx
12:10:46                                     ^^^^^^^ No such command
12:10:46 
12:10:47 Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
```

The build.ps1 script has not changed. The build.cake script has not changed. Jenkins was not updated since the last successful builds nor any of the add-ins.

If I remove "-target=Default" from the argument list, I just get the same error on "-configuration=Release" indicating unknown command: "Release".

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The possible root cause of this failure is the cake version update (0.38.x --> 1.0)

You have two ways to fix this issue

1. Change the Argument Syntex - arguments should always be called with multi-dash syntax (e.g. --target=Foo) instead of (e.g. -target=Foo)
   Refer: https://cakebuild.net/docs/getting-started/upgrade
2. Pinning the cake version

Specified the version of Cake in the tools/packages.config file
Refer: https://cakebuild.net/docs/writing-builds/reproducible-builds/pinning-cake-version

Comment: This was the cause of the problem! UPdated all scripts/Jenkins jobs to use "--". Thank you!

Comment: Fixed an issue we started seeing in our Gitlab CI/CD pipeline as well - much appreciated!